# Swift Impossible Type Inference

Tags: swift, swift3, nsurl, type-inference

I am trying to load a file from my app bundle in Swift 3, and I came across a weird situation with the Swift type inferencing. If I use the following code, I get an error on the third line that says `Value of optional type "String?" not unwrapped`.

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:Bundle.main.bundlePath)
let url2 = url.appendingPathComponent("foo.txt")
let path:String = url2?.path
```

To fix the error I unwrap the value on the third line by changing it to:

```
let path:String = url2?.path!
```

I now get the error `Cannot force unwrap value of a non-optional type 'String'`. It seems like Swift can't determine whether the path property is a `String` or a `String?`. The autocomplete feature in Xcode says it is a `String`, but the docs say it is a `String?`.

The suggested fix by Xcode for the first error was to replace `url2?.path` with `(url2?.path)!`, which finally ended up working, but I have no idea why this works and the other ways don't.

```
let path:String = (url2?.path)!
```

What is going on? Is this a type inference bug in Swift, or am I missing something super obvious

Comment: `let fooBundleURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("foo.txt")`

Comment: `let fooPath = fooBundleURL.path`

Comment: @LeoDabus I agree that works, but my question is why the provided code does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift, Optional chaining like:

```
let path:String = url2?.path!
```

... is interpreted as:

```
let path:String = url2 != nil ? url2!.path!
                              : nil
```

As you see the type of `path` is non-Optional `String`, so the expression causes error.

(`url2`'s type is `URL?`, so the type of property `path` is `String`, not `String?`.)

---

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I would re-write your code as:

```
let url = Bundle.main.bundleURL
let url2 = url.appendingPathComponent("foo.txt")
let path:String = url2.path
```

Shorter, and no worry about Optionals.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to unwrap `url2`

`appendingPathComponent` returns an optional value and you are trying to access it without unwrapping it.

So,

```
let url2 = url.appendingPathComponent("foo.txt")!
```

or

```
guard let url2 = url.appendingPathComponent("foo.txt") else { }
```

should fix it

**EDIT**

```
let path:String? = url2?.path
```

works also

Comment: The `?` after the `url2` should account for that. If you put a `?` after an optional, then it stops executing if the optional is nil, but continues if the optional has a value.

Comment: He is using NSURL when he should be using URL also URL appendingPathComponent  methods return URL non optional `func appendingPathComponent(_ pathComponent: String) -> URL`

Comment: @LeoDabus Agreed, I probably should be, and thanks for the tip. I'm coming back to swift after a while, and don't know what has been renamed without the NS prefix.

Comment: @Aderis be aware that you can't write to the bundle folder https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html. from the docs This is the app’s bundle. This directory contains the app and all of its resources.
You cannot write to this directory. To prevent tampering, the bundle directory is signed at installation time. Writing to this directory changes the signature and prevents your app from launching. You can, however, gain read-only access to any resources stored in the apps bundle.

Comment: `url2?.path!` is the same as `url2.flatMap { $0.path! }` which doesn't make sense because `path` isn't an optional property.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "foo", withExtension: "txt")!
let path:String = url.path
```

Comment: `Bundle` now has a method `url(forResource:withExtension:)`. You can write something like `let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "foo", withExtension: "txt")!` `let path:String = url.path`.

Comment: ok, Thanks for this suggestion i will apply it, and edit my answer.